# How can I add a certain value to a random block in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

What I want to do is assign a number (such as 2) to two random spot in the array.  Here's how I setup my array.

```
public static void print_array(int[][] array) {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        System.out.print("\n-----------------\n" +
                         "|  ");
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            if (col != array[row].length) {
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + "|  ");
            if (col == array[row].length) {
                System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n-----------------");
}
```

I then call `print_array` in the main method to display the array.  Then to add the number I need to use this method:

```
public static void placeBlock(int[][] array) {
}
```

How can I place an integer in a random spot in the array?

Comment: check my answer hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo operator. This operator return the remainder. 
Eg.

```
2 % 3 returns 2 (It is lesser that 3 the second operand)
3 % 3 returns 0 (It is lesser that 3 the second operand)
3 % 2 returns 1 (It is lesser that 2 the second operand)
```

Assuming you have 2 random numbers num1 and num2 & you know that dimension of you 2D Array is MxN. That is M rows and N columns.
So when you do

```
num1 % M returns a number between 0...M
num2 % N returns a number between 0...N
```

This enables you to do:

```
array[num1%M][num2%N]=2;
```

---

Edit as per comment : 
If you are generating random numbers then:

```
Random randomGenerator=new Random();
int num1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(array.length);
int num2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(array[0].length);
```

In this case you get the random number as per the length so you can use it directly

```
array[num1][num2]=2;
```

Comment: It may help to explain how to get two random numbers. :P.

Comment: @Zéychin I left that for OP cause it might be an output from some other function. But it make an edit as per your comment !

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][]array={{3,4,5},{1,8,3},{33,7,5}};
        print_array(array);
        placeBlock(array,2);
        print_array(array);


    }
    public static void placeBlock(int[][] array,int value) {
        Random rand=new Random();
        int randRow=rand.nextInt(array.length);
        int randCol=rand.nextInt(array[0].length);
        array[randRow][randCol]=value;
    }
    public static void print_array(int[][] array) {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("\n-----------------\n" +
                             "|  ");
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                if (col != array[row].length) {
                    System.out.print(array[row][col] + "|  ");
                if (col == array[row].length) {
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n-----------------");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but it's printing only at [0][2] and [2][3].

Comment: i dont think so. just run 4-5 times and check

Comment: I had the seed set to `1` instead of just `Random()`. It works great. Thanks!